# Is BSD license compatible with Apache?

Tags: licensing, bsd-license, apache

Can I develop a BSD-licensed software that extends an Apache-licensed software (and vice-versa)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The short answer is that if you use open source software in your project, you must satisfy all the requirements laid out in that license.

Neither BSD nor Apache 2.0 is a "viral" license, meaning AFAIK it makes no demands on the other source code you include it with.  That also means that unlike GPL, you aren't releasing a "product" under a BSD or Apache license, but each file or section of code is licensed under the license that the author released it under.

So you could have a project where one module was BSD and one module was Apache, and I see no reason why you couldn't distribute that, as long as you were explicit about it.  Note that IANAL.

Do you have the right to take Apache licensed code and re-license it as BSD?  I highly doubt it.  I believe Apache has a couple more restrictions on it than BSD.  You'd have to keep the original copyright notice, of course, but I also believe you have to do a bit extra when releasing changes to it, and you couldn't (or at least shouldn't) remove those conditions by changing the license.

[You may include (extend) BSD licensed code in an Apache v2.0 licensed code base, including source code managed by the Apache Software Foundation](http://www.apache.org/legal/resolved.html#category-a).

> For the purposes of being a dependency to an Apache product, which licenses are considered to be similar in terms to the Apache License 2.0?
>   Works under the following licenses may be included within Apache products:
>
> • BSD (without advertising clause). Including variants:
>
> ◦ BSD 2-clause
>
> ◦ BSD 3-clause

Please consult **your** attorney for risk and compliance advise.

Comment: can I take Apache licensed code and release it under Apache (original) and BSD (dual licensed)?

Comment: The first sentence applies to any license, whether it be a free, open or closed source license.

Answer (score 16):

Short answer: **Yes**.  The Apache Software License was based in large part on BSD and MIT style licenses.  The common understanding while I was working on Apache code a while back was that you could incorporate BSD, MIT, and similar licensed libraries but you could not do the same for GPL based licenses.

If you have further questions, I highly recommend going directly to Apache:

- http://apache.org/foundation/faq.html#license
- http://apache.org/licenses/
- http://apache.org/foundation/licence-FAQ.html
- http://apache.org/legal/
- http://www.apache.org/legal/resolved.html#category-a

They are a group of really nice guys, and they are pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

The best answer for this can be found in the apache third party license policy. This is the policy that all apache projects have to follow when using libs with other licenses. As you can see BSD is listed in Category A - Authorized licenses. So it should be no problem using this license. You can also find policies for other licenses here which is quite helpful. In fact I think the Apache policy may also be a good starting point for you own licensing policy if you work for a company.

http://www.apache.org/legal/resolved.html

Comment: New link: http://www.apache.org/legal/resolved.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is very useful site:

- [**Easily to compare different types of licenses.**](https://tldrlegal.com/)
- And [**Choose A License**](http://choosealicense.com/)

In your case:
[**apache-2.0**](https://tldrlegal.com/license/apache-license-2.0-%28apache-2.0%29) and [**BSD**](https://tldrlegal.com/license/bsd-3-clause-license-%28revised%29).

In both of them you must:

- Include copyright

But in Apache, unlike BSD **you must**:

- Include License
- State Changes
- Include Notice

---

**UPD**

This info taken from [tldrlegal.com](http://tldrlegal.com)

And as they notice:

> This is only a short summary of the Full Text. No information on TLDRLegal is legal advice.

Please, see discussion in comments with @DmitryAlexandrov for more info.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the issue of extending an apache licensed project with a BSD license.

Comment: @MichaelT this answer helps to understand difference between these licenses. Thus, of course, help to understand the aspects in which they are compatible, and which is not.

Comment: What do mean by ‘unlike BSD [Licence]’? BSDL (all three of them) *does* require to include copyright notices and licence conditions both in source and binary distributions.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov probably I missed smth. I found it here: https://tldrlegal.com/license/bsd-3-clause-license-(revised) and here: https://tldrlegal.com/license/apache-license-2.0-(apache-2.0) in column **must**

Comment: @skywinder I guess, you missed [the text of the licence](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:BSD_3Clause). :-) Please, don’t delete the answer, it might be useful as an illustration on why such wiki-pages as tldrlegal.com are harmful.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Got it, I updated answer, to notice users about potential mismatches.